# How to open Microsoft Access MDB file in centos6?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, centos, centos6

I am using centos6.

How do I open an MDB file from Microsoft Access?

In this case i just need to see what are tables and data  in this file.

Comment: You run Microsoft Access inside Wine and you open the database. That's the answer to the question as you ask it, perhaps you'll want to change it to actually be about Java in some way other than you adding that as a tag.

Comment: what is wine? .i am new to centos

Comment: If you don't change your question to actually be about Java and programming, then this is an off-topic question better suited for superuser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact asking about how to open an Access database from a Java application then you should have a look at

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

If you just want to open the database in a GUI to look at the tables then you could do that with LibreOffice Base (or OpenOffice Base) as described in

[Is it possible to open an Access 2010 database file without using Wine or VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/187389/323236)